# Strange character Laravel

Tags: laravel, character

I am using Laravel 5.3

Hello,

A stranger character "-" is showing at every pages.

See my files:
[image: My Controller]
[image: Result in html]

My View blade contains only a single `<h1> tag`.

```
<h1>New Test</h1>
```

Comment: You have an echo or some kind of print in some point of your code. Have you tried the all mighty ctrl+f?

Comment: You should have that symbol in Layout or view

Comment: No.
Its a pure code. nothing more
No echo, no debug, nothing.
Ctrl+f find millions of this.

Comment: even in 'Welcome' and errors pages this appers

Comment: Maybe it's not a "-" but something that outputs that. If it appears in every page then it's something outside that controller. Try looking at the code that is being executed in every request.

Comment: Chances are you've just hit the `-` key just before an open `<?php`. If it's appearing on every page then the usual culprit is at the top of your routes file.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's appearing on every page, you will have 2 main places where it will be:

1. The top of your web/routes.php file.
2. It will most likely be located inside your layout file. And you probably are looking for the extra '-' inside your view file which extends the layout file.